# jump from main activity to last visited activity

Tags: android

Lets suppose I am at 4th activity of my app and I have ten activities. I close the activity from 4th level now when i reopen my activity again 
i have a button on main activity when i click on it I must have to go on 4th activity where i left last time. Now what I do is that I saved every activity number or ID in Shared preference like that

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_level1);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putInt("level", 4);
editor.apply();
```

Then i retrieve it in main activity like this:

```
btnconti.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      int restoredLevel = prefs.getInt("level", 0);
      if (restoredLevel >0) {
      }
   }
});
```

Now can any body tell me how i can jump to my last visited activity?

Comment: You just call the intent from that if condition

Comment: thankyou george thomas your suggestion is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have seperate Activities for all 10 activities u can call an intent as follows inside multiple if conditions of restoredlevel

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivtyOfyourlevel.class)
startActivity(i);
```